# Are interrupts disabled when an interrupt is being handled?

Tags: x86-64, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Im working on a project with a monocore cpu. Imagine I make a software interrupt by calling int 80h. How can I be sure no other interrupt occurs while mine is being handled. For example, wouldn't the timer tick interrupt the other interrupt. How is this taken care off? If interrupts are disabled, when is this done and how. All that I know is that when an interrupt occurrs, the current PCB is pushed and that hardware interrupts are handled by the pic.

Comment: Interrupts and their handling is very specific to CPU type. Which you haven't told us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Im working with this basic os https://bitbucket.org/RowDaBoat/x64barebones/wiki/Home. Take for example intel 80386

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica and how is this done, by using the cli instruction?

Comment: So the CPU family is x86-64? This is *hardware* specific, not software. The OS is irrelevant.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes

Comment: The behavior depends on whether the IDT entry is an interrupt gate or a trap gate. Intel SDM vol 3, 6.12.1.2: “The only difference between an interrupt gate and a trap gate is the way the processor handles the IF flag in the EFLAGS register. When accessing an exception- or interrupt-handling procedure through an interrupt gate, the processor clears the IF flag to prevent other interrupts from interfering with the current interrupt handler.”

Comment: @chux, software interrupts are invoked by an instruction, so they can’t be disabled. And of course NMI isn’t masked by the IF flag.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, it can be OS-specific in that the OS chooses whether to use a trap gate or interrupt gate.

Comment: The PIC and the APIC both have prioritized interrupts. In an interrupt handler where IF is set, only a **higher priority** interrupt can be delivered, until EOI is sent to the PIC/APIC.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: IF set or cleared doesn't affect what happens if you run `int 0x80` (a "software interrupt"), or other synchronous exceptions like dividing by zero or page-fault.  I think you got it backwards in [your earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948986/are-interrupts-disabled-when-an-interrupt-is-being-handled#comment113082260_63948986): Interrupt handlers often run with hardware interrupts disabled (although not always; some let higher priority interrupts interrupt them), but software interrupts can't be disabled.

Comment: @PeterCordes Remove comments.